# Refused to connect to 'http://someURL' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src http://someURL"

Tags: nginx, http

Well, that's the error which comes up from my browser console, I am working with one domain and that domain has only one sub-domain, and I still don't have access to the sub-domain. Actually I am receiving some other errors.

My guess is that the mistake I have is in the `add_header Content-Security-Policy`, in the `connect-src` part.
:
this is the domain part and the `Content-Security-Policy`:

```
server {
    large_client_header_buffers 1 1K;

    listen       80;
    server_name  www.just4bettors.mobi  just4bettors.mobi;
    root   /home/c0pt/capilleira/capilleiraclickandgamblemobile/www;

    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm;
        ...
    }

    add_header Content-Security-Policy
    "default-src 'self' http://just4bettors.mobi:1337;
     connect-src http://just4bettors.mobi
                 http://just4bettors.mobi:1337
                 http://www.just4bettors.mobi
                 http://www.just4bettors.mobi:1337";
}
```

and this is the part for the sub-domain:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name www.desktop.just4bettors.mobi  desktop.just4bettors.mobi;
   root   /home/c0pt/capilleira/capilleiraclickandgambleweb/dist;
   location / {
        index index.html index.htm;
        ...
   }

   add_header Content-Security-Policy add_header
   "default-src 'self' http://www.just4bettors.mobi;
    connect-src http://just4bettors.mobi
                http://just4bettors.mobi:1337
                http://www.just4bettors.mobi
                http://www.just4bettors.mobi:1337
                http://www.desktop.just4bettors.mobi:1337
                http://www.desktop.just4bettors.mobi";
}
```

this part of the errors I am getting in the console

```
Refused to connect to 'http://www.desktop.just4bettors.mobi/views/accFiguresModal.html' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src http://just4bettors.mobi http://just4bettors.mobi:1337 http://www.just4bettors.mobi http://www.just4bettors.mobi:1337".
```

the issue actually comes up only when I try to connect to `www.desktop.just4bettors.mobi` but if I put `www.just4bettors.mobi` everything works properly

so, where is my error here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add header Content-Security-Policy to your meta tag:

```
"connect-src http://just4bettors.mobi http://just4bettors.mobi:1337 http://www.just4bettors.mobi http://www.desktop.just4bettors.mobi;"
```

Complete meta tag will be like this:

```
"default-src 'self' http://www.just4bettors.mobi; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src 'self' http://placehold.it https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://s-static.ak.facebook.com https://assets.zendesk.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com https://fonts.gstatic.com  https://themes.googleusercontent.com https://assets.zendesk.com; font-src 'self' https://themes.googleusercontent.com https://fonts.gstatic.com; frame-src 'self'; object-src 'none'; connect-src http://just4bettors.mobi http://just4bettors.mobi:1337 http://www.just4bettors.mobi http://www.desktop.just4bettors.mobi;"
```

Comment: Care to add explanation for readers in the future?